# Track down out-of-bounds access on iPhone

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, memory

I work on an average (~ 20k lines of code, Objective-C mixed with C++), and I am figthing to hunt down an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I have tried all the common techniques (like enabling NSZombie, guard edges,etc.) So far, I have ruled out the possibility to access a released object, and the double-free error.

It seems that something writes on a memory space where it shouldn't. But, as many memory errors, it's not happening all the time, and it's not crashing always in the same place.
(Sometimes I receive the "object was modified after being freed" message).

Sometimes, the overwritten memory belongs to the **allocator**, and it crashes on malloc, or on free().

And, of course, some changes in the app may influence the bug's behaviour - if I try to comment out parts of the code, the error appears less often, so it's more difficult to find it.

Finally, I have been looking into using **valgrind**, but it seems that all those who used it worked on the simulator. but my code must run on the actual device (some code is **ARM**-specific)

Are there **any** general tips on how to debug such errors?

Note: The app involves **video processing**, so the amount of memory used is fairly large.

Comment: If the memory used is fairly large, are you seeing what your memory landscape looks like in case you receive a low memory warning? In such a case, the OS will unload anything not on screen. You may be getting an issue there. I assume you're not using ARC?

Comment: I do not receive memory warnings, and 'fairly large' means a dozen of MB, and not 100MB. But what is ARC? Automatic ref count? If yes, the answer is no. I use shared_ptr for most C++ code, and simple pointers for ObjC

Comment: Do you get a stack trace when it crashes if you run it in the debugger?

Comment: Sometimes, but it's not always the same stack, so I think it's not neccesarily relevant.

Comment: Are you using Objective-C block objects?  Multi-threading?  you mention you're just using 'simple pointers' for Objective-C - are you relying on an autorelease pool or do you manually alloc/retain/release?

Answer (score 0):

There are some special tools available on the XCode. You could try to use them in order to analyse your code.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/index.html
It will produce some warning in case of invalid objects usage so it could help you to find a problem.

Comment: Ok then there is the only one solution in my opinion. And this is to incorporate the unit-tests in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that the C++ code is causing the issue you could copy the C++ out of your iPhone project and create a Mac project.  With this you could set up various stress tests.  And, you should be able to use valgrind as well.

Comment: The ARM code is in the C++ part, but I think I'll follow your suggestion to rule out the Objective-C part (Run it under Valgrind)